# Placement of linear voltage regulators (L7806CV & L78M05ABV) and N-Channel MOSFET (P30N06LE) circuit for maximum power efficiency

Tags: mosfet, pcb, circuit-design, linear-regulator

Two simple questions I hope.

I'm running a circuit powered by 8 NiMH batteries and need to drop the voltage from 9.6 to 5V (L78M05ABV) and 6V (L7806CV) to power different components.

Currently, I have the 9.6V line running separately to the 5V and 6V regulators. The subsequent 6V line is controlled with a N-Channel MOSFET (P30N06LE) after the linear regulator in the circuit, which powers on for two seconds and then turns off.

The questions:

Would placing the MOSFET before the 6V regulator increase the efficiency of the circuit?

If not, would it increase the efficiency to have the 9.6V line pass through the 6V regulator and then the 5V regulator, rather than each of them separately?

My understanding of how linear regulators work suggests that it would, but I'm looking for a second opinion. I'm considering a buck converter, though the voltage drop is fairly low at a maximum of 1.5A.

Comment: For maximum power efficiency, the best place for linear regulators like the 7805 is ... the bin. Consider switching regulators (buck converters) instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Placing the FET before the 6V regulator definitely makes higher efficiency, because the regulator also consumes current when it's powered. Whether shutting it down makes a huge difference or not, it obviously depends on how much your 6V load is, and what is the quiescent current of the regulator, and what is the consumption of the rest of the circuit. If your 5V circuit consumes 1A, 5mA for the 7806 does not make much of a difference. But it's higher anyway, if you shut the regulator down too.
2. You can't power the 5V regulator from the 6V regulator, as 6V is not high enough voltage for the 7805 to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't put the 7805 in series with the 7806.  The [7805](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf) requires that the input voltage be at least 2 volts higher than the output voltage.  You need at least 7V on the input of the 7805 to get a regulated 5V output.  You can't operate the 7805 on the 6V output of the 7806.

[image]

2. If the point of the MOSFET is to shutoff power from the battery, then it should be between the battery and the regulators rather than between the regulator and circuit.  The 7805 draws around 5 milliamperes even when there's no load on it.

[image]

---

"Efficiency" and "linear regulator" are two items that kind of contradict one another.

If you need efficiency, you should go with the buck converter.

If you need efficiency and low noise, then you can combine a buck converter with a low drop out linear regulator.